# Rails single-table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I have a class `TrafficRule` that is defined like this:

```
TrafficRule
- name:string
- type:string
- details:text
```

The `details` parameter will be a JSON object that will store a set of details for a given traffic rule, and the `type` parameter will define what that JSON object looks like.  So for one rule type the object might be an array, and for another the object might be a hash.  I would like the TrafficRule STI class to define what the details object looks like.

Has anyone come across a design pattern that solves this use case well?  Maybe I need to change the way my objects are associated?

Ideally, I would love to be able to edit this object in ActiveAdmin and have the form actually customize for the type of input that it's expecting.

Comment: If you're using JSON in your schema, might be worth checking out [Postgres](http://postgresql.org/) which has a very powerful native JSON datatype. Rails supports this in your schema as `:json` without needing to add a `serialize` declaration.

Comment: I'm using Postgres, but I wasn't aware of the json data type.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having schemaless data and STI might be a little confused from a design perspective, one of those should be sufficient without needing the other, but it can still work.

You can always trigger the proper view for this using something like:

```
render(partial: "#{model.name.underscore}_edit")
```

Where you'd have partials named something like `_example_edit` and `_another_example_edit` for the Example and AnotherExample classes respectively.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for how to structure the design better?  I've been scratching my head about it for a while now.

Comment: Not really enough information in your question to make a call here. I'd try the simplest thing that could possibly work, and if that's insufficient, incrementally add to it until it does.